# Code signing identities not found in Xcode server

Tags: xcode, bots, carthage, xcode-server

Using Xcode 7B4 and Server 5B4 with a [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) project. To build the project I need to first build it's dependencies. So I added a Before Integration step to the bot with the following code:

```
echo "Bootstrapping dependencies..."
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
cd Alchemic
carthage bootstrap --use-ssh --use-submodules
echo "Ready."
```

Running this myself everything works. But when the bot runs it I get this:

> **CodeSign error:** No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.
>   **CodeSign error:** code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 9.0'
>   A shell task failed with exit code 65

Checking the bot I have myself as the team and scanning the servers directories it appears to have all the required provisioning files. So I'm guessing that Server's user does not have access to the keys or something like that.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: I ran into something similar with cocoa pods, not sure how Carthage does it but cocoa pods created frameworks they also needed to be code signed and provisioned. Not sure if u have that set up already or not

Comment: Thanks for the response. One of the great things about Carthage is that it does not mess with your project at all. It only manages and builds dependencies. So it leaves you total freedom as to how to include our code. Unlike CocoaPods which stomps all over everything. Because Carthage builds each project individually, code signing is handled on a project by project basis. So I think this is more of a general issue than a Carthage specific one.

Comment: interesting, I'll have to try it out on one of my projects

Comment: Yep. Big fan of Carthage now. Might not be so good for people who are not familiar with handling frameworks. But it's working well in several projects I have. Also like that it's capable of building .gitsubmodule files which makes managing git projects really easy.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue. The solution for me was:

1. From Xcode **on your local machine**, open `Preferences` -> `Accounts` -> double click on the team associated with your apple ID (you need one :) ) -> in the `Signing identity` panel, select an identity and click the cog icon to `export`. Save this to a file.
2. Upload the generated `.p12` file **to your build machine**, and add it to the **System** keychain (not to the user's) by dragging it to the *Keychain Access* window
3. On the build machine *Keychain Access*, navigate to the certificate(s) you just installed (it should be under `System` -> `Certificates`) and click the arrow next to the name to expand and see the private key. Right click on the key -> `Get info` -> `Access control` tab, and either allow all apps to access this item (probably unsafe) or add the `codesign` app to the list of applications that are allowed to use this key
4. Make sure, on *Server* on the build machine, that the `XCode` section is enabled and added to the corresponding development team for that certificate.

Comment: Looks like the new Xcode (7 Beta 4) doesn't support exporting the identities and for some reason they are not appearing in the keychain anymore. Hmmm....

Comment: In Xcode 7 offers a new option "Export Developer Accounts". The file created is a zip file which you can extract to see the exported provisioning profiles and certificates. Anybody know how to import this file on the Xcode server?

Comment: @Awsed just add those items to the keychain?

Comment: Thanks- Adding p12 file to SYSTEM keychain helped me with the code sign error on my xcode server machine.  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues with Xcode Server bots and code signing. I'm running Server 5.1 and Xcode 7.3. What ultimately helped me work through them was this blog post: http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/

Namely, the parts of the post most helpful were:

1. Make sure that your provisioning profiles are copied into the Xcode Server directory located at: `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles/`
   Xcode Server can't see the profiles that Xcode automatically downloads from the developer portal to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. You can either copy those into place or manually download them from the web and move them over.
2. Make sure the signing key (private key) and certificate are in the **System** keychain. Again, Xcode creates these within the context of your user account. If you generated them with Xcode on the server, then simply copy them from your **login** keychain to the **System** one. If you are importing from other computer using a .p12, make sure you import to the **System** keychain in Keychain Access.

For more detail, check out that blog post. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers seem to be working, make sure you have the latest `Command Line Tools` selected.

> *Xcode Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools*

[image: Command Line Tools Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

It is very easy. Go to XCode Preferences -> Accounts -> Click your Apple ID and Press View Details button Press Refresh at the end press Done. It will be okay. [image]

Comment: No that does not fix the problem. This is not a XCode problem.